# Excel output XML using XSLT

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, xslt, xsd

I am attempting to use [xml2json-xslt](https://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/) to convert my Excel generated XML to JSON data. It is written in XSL 1.0 so I can run it from the browser and it works just fine. However I would like to include it in my workflow from Excel so I can automatically map my output without this additional step.

Is it possible to export XML from Excel and transform it using an XSL in one go?

**NOTE:** I am using the XML map export feature of Excel with a schema definition (XSD) and not saving in the default Excel schema.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to export XML from Excel and transform it using an XSL in one go?

Yes. Use the following process:

- Export using the following script: 
  [Export Excel to XML in VBA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6950/Export-Excel-to-XML-in-VBA)
- Invoke msxml on the output file using the following script:
  [Convert XML to CSV with XSL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13975/Convert-XML-to-CSV-with-XSL)
- Replace `c:\testme.xsl` with `xml2json.xslt`
- Replace `c:\testme.xml` with the output from the export from Excel
- Combine both scripts into one file once they work separately